# Why caching in python works such way

Tags: python, caching

```
for a in range(2):
    print(id({}))  # 2444803983552, 2444803983552

for a in range(2):
    obj = {}
    print(id(obj))  # 2347467557056, 2347469009408
```

Why does it work so? I thought that in both ways dict would relate to different memory units

Comment: I think it's because the first time you're looking up for a literal value, whereas the second time, you're assigning that literal value to an object, then looking up on that object.

Comment: You can see the same thing with `x = {} ; print(id({}), id({}), id(x))`

Comment: When objects get garbage collected or are no longer referenced by anything, the id may be re-used for new objects. See the same example with a custom class https://pastebin.com/kvAHmXEd